# Использование функции из главного файла в фрагменте

Tags: java, android

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Имеется функция в MainActivity. Как мне использовать функцию из нее в фрагментах(в другом файле)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно по разному. Самый простой способ - получить ссылку на активити во фрагменте и скастовать её к типу активити. Типа так:

```
//где-то во фрагменте, например в `onCreateView` методе
((MainActivity)getActivity()).mainActivityMethodName();
```

Comment: .mainActivityMethodName(). Почему-то это не определяет

Comment: Представьте название вашего метода

Comment: Почему-то не находит

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос. Без кода не помочь